# Getting the complete list of AEs x drug with openFDA

Tags: openfda

Can one get ALL AEs per single drug instead of the most frequent ones? Example Ibrutinib 2,921 reports; AEs reported 1,696 in 10 categories. How can I get the remaining list of less frequent events up to the last one?

Comment: Can you post your API call as a link, please?

Comment: Hi Hans, sorry I do not know what an API link is. I know I have an API key but that is all. Could you help ? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by categories. If you wanted to get the top 100 reactions for events with a medicinal product listed as Ibrutinib, then you can use the openfda section to narrow your search down and then the count api to get a list. Here is an example: http://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.generic_name.exact:IBRUTINIB&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=100

Please note there are limits to how count works and you might have to be creative to get a full list. http://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference is quite rich.

Comment: You can also practice with the API using this tool. https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/

Comment: Thank you Hans for your comment. Searching for ibrutinib with the "patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact" syntax I see reports (2,921) and   histograms with  most common events. My aim is to get  all AEs reported and not the 10 most common ones. Probably you are familiar with the "drugcite.com" way of listing and downloading the excel folio with all the listings. How can I get a similar representation from openFDA? i.e.:  total number of reports and the complete list of reported AEs in them,  possibly as all-grade/serious events.  Do  you think it is possible? Best regards

Comment: You would be able to expand the limit by using the parameter `limit=100`, however, there is a max value of 100 for limit on the API, so you would not be able a full histogram this way. Typically, in this case, users will carve up there query in some manner to limit scope of the query (such as a date range of a month) and then execute for all of the range intervals (roughly 144 for the drug event API). If you want complete accuracy and cannot carve up the query, then there is always the downloads route, but you would have to iterate over all of the data. once downloaded it takes about a few min

Comment: CORRECTION: I mistyped the limit for the count parameter. It is 1000 not 100.

Comment: Thank you so much Hans, this is going to be very helpful. Just to check if I got it correctly. In my example, ibrutinib there were 2,921 reports, therefore there will be presumably much more that 3,000 AEs to collect.  Can I limit the query for both 1000 and then introduce also a date range, or I can use only one of them. In my example, then, it can only be the data range since beginning of the date of marketing (Nov 2013) in intervals to be tested not to exceed 1000 counts ? Correct ?

Comment: You can have quite a few query criteria at the same time, just separate them with `+AND+`.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I will follow your precious indications and start practicing. If you do not see me again in this arena, that will mean that your efforts have been quite successful even in this desperate case! Thank you so much